# Taking fixed values into account in combination with repetition

Tags: combinatorics

Today's Advent Of Code problem [(this one)](https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/12) is making me think a lot about a mathematical solution to this question. So basically, if I solve a problem using the old balls and urns approach, is it possible to filter out of the answer values that dont fit in a certain "mask". For example:

I have 5 balls and 2 dividers, so ||OOOOO

We can find the ways to distribute the balls in the urns by

(5+2)!/5!2!= 7 choose 2 (sorry i cant post images due to low reputation)

but now, lets say that the fifth position, needs to be a ball, and the second needs to be a divider. Then

OO|O|OO

this distribution is not a valid one, but this one is:

O|OOO|O

In the end, the question is: how can I get the number of combinations with repetition that respect an arbitrary amount of restriction on the final distribution?

Comment: You are clear, I hope, that the answer to the question you're asking is not the same as the answer to the question in the Advent of Code problem?

Comment: Just arbitrarily say that those positions need to be their respective objects.  Now, arrange everything else that remains around those restrictions.  Here you have $5$ remaining positions left to decide with one of those five positions still needing to be a divider and four needing to be balls giving $\frac{5!}{4!1!}$